# Display Real path of (.lnk) shortcut file using C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to display real Path (target ) of shortcut (.lnk) file .So i copy and paste (test.lnk)in corrent folder of project and I'm trying to display its target

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <objidl.h>   /* For IPersistFile */
#include <shlobj.h>   /* For IShellLink */
#include "objbase.h"

using namespace std;


/*********************************************************************
* Function......: ResolveShortcut
* Parameters....: lpszShortcutPath - string that specifies a path
                                     and file name of a shortcut
*          lpszFilePath - string that will contain a file name
* Returns.......: S_OK on success, error code on failure
* Description...: Resolves a Shell link object (shortcut)
*********************************************************************/
HRESULT ResolveShortcut(/*in*/ LPCTSTR lpszShortcutPath,
                        /*out*/ LPTSTR lpszFilePath)
{
    HRESULT hRes = E_FAIL;
    IShellLink*    psl     = NULL;

        // buffer that receives the null-terminated string
        // for the drive and path
    TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
        // buffer that receives the null-terminated
        // string for the description
    TCHAR szDesc[MAX_PATH];
        // structure that receives the information about the shortcut
    WIN32_FIND_DATA wfd;
    WCHAR wszTemp[MAX_PATH];

    lpszFilePath[0] = '\0';

    // Get a pointer to the IShellLink interface
    hRes = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLink,
                            NULL,
                            CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                            IID_IShellLink,
                            (void**)&psl);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hRes))
    {
        // Get a pointer to the IPersistFile interface
        IPersistFile*  ppf     = NULL;
        psl->QueryInterface(IID_IPersistFile, (void **) &ppf);


        // IPersistFile is using LPCOLESTR,
                // so make sure that the string is Unicode
#if !defined _UNICODE
        MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, lpszShortcutPath,
                                       -1, wszTemp, MAX_PATH);
#else
        wcsncpy(wszTemp, lpszShortcutPath, MAX_PATH);
#endif

        // Open the shortcut file and initialize it from its contents
        hRes = ppf->Load(wszTemp, STGM_READ);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hRes))
        {
            // Try to find the target of a shortcut,
                        // even if it has been moved or renamed
            hRes = psl->Resolve(NULL, SLR_UPDATE);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hRes))
            {
                // Get the path to the shortcut target
                hRes = psl->GetPath(szPath,
                                     MAX_PATH, &wfd, SLGP_RAWPATH);
                if (FAILED(hRes))
                    return hRes;

                // Get the description of the target
                hRes = psl->GetDescription(szDesc,
                                             MAX_PATH);
                if (FAILED(hRes))
                    return hRes;

                lstrcpyn(lpszFilePath, szPath, MAX_PATH);

            }
        }
    }

    return hRes;
}

int main(void)
{

    LPCTSTR lpszShortcutPath =("test.lnk");
    TCHAR szFilePath[MAX_PATH];

    HRESULT hRes =ResolveShortcut(lpszShortcutPath, szFilePath);
     cout << TEXT("Succeeded: path = ") <<hRes ;
    return 0;
}
```

it displays Succeeded: path = -2134343

Can someone help me to display real target of .lnk file and its  Description.

Comment: Why do you print `hRes` instead of `szFilePath`? And why don't you check for errors from your function?

Comment: because, when I put  szFilePath , It doesn't display anything ( Succeeded: path =          )

Comment: `cout << TEXT("Succeeded: path = ") <<hRes`-> `cout << TEXT("Succeeded: path = ") << szFilePath` and check for errors, test.lnk might not exist.

Comment: Step through the code with your debugger. Most likely one of the `SUCCEEDED(hRes)` returns `FALSE`, or one of the `FAILED(hRes)` returns `TRUE`.

Comment: Considering that `ResolveShortcut` returns a *negative* number indicates that there was an error. You should probably check it out.

Comment: _because, when I put szFilePath , It doesn't display anything_. It's a bit like if your diesel car won't start you empty the tank and fill it with gasoline and expect the engine to run.

Comment: The function runs well , before any return Statement (I added a message ).And i find that any Else block executes .

Comment: You possibly forgot to call `CoInitialize(NULL);`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz .Thanks a Lot post it and i will make it as usefull answer ,It works know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably forgot to call [`CoInitialize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678543(v=vs.85).aspx)

Start of your main function:

```
int main(void)
{
  CoInitialize(NULL);   //<< add

  LPCTSTR lpszShortcutPath....

  CoUninitialize();     //<< add
}
```

Comment: ... and `CoUninitialize()` before returning from main()

Comment: If LPCTSTR lpszShortcutPath =("test.lnk") then szFilePath take null Value but if LPCTSTR lpszShortcutPath =("test.txt.lnk") . I add the real exentsion to the file then it works well .Have you an idea how it can work with only .lnk extension

Comment: @MedAminBelGhith I don't know, sorry. But that would make another good question with the WINAPI tag.

Comment: Are you sure that the actual name of the shortcut file *isn't* `test.txt.lnk` ?  (It seems unlikely that using the wrong name would make it work better.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston , I'm sure . Try it . And until now i didn't find solution .          https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45147024/displaying-target-of-and-real-extension-of-shortcut-using-c

Comment: @MichaelWalz .I know that like always , you will find the good answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45147024/displaying-target-of-and-real-extension-of-shortcut-using-c

Comment: I can't reproduce.  Using the code in the (deleted) question, with only minor changes to make it build in Unicode mode, I can resolve the destination only if I provide the actual name of the shortcut file.  If I add the extension of the target, it doesn't work - except for those shortcut files that do in fact include the extension of the target as part of their name.